Trying to connect to Solr Cloud using zookeeper instead of a simple HttpClient from R?
There is a package called solrium which has been great for me until the network timeouts began happening. Our production servers run SolrCloud, managed by a zookeeper quorum, and my only theory I have is that the simple http client behind solrium is not properly being managed by the zookeeper quorum and keeps dropping my connection, for example this verbose output:
 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 < Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 
 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; style-src 
 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'; worker-src 'self';
 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 < Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
 < Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
 < Content-Encoding: gzip
 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 < 
 * Connection #27 to host <IP> left intact
 * Too old connection (120 seconds idle), disconnect it
 * Connection 27 seems to be dead
 * Closing connection 27
 *   Trying <IP>:8080...
 * Connected to FQDN (IP) port 8080 (#28)
 * Server auth using Basic

Solrium uses R6 objects and builds a connection via a simple http client from the package crul. I build the client with a simple call:
  cli<-SolrClient$new(host = SolrServer,port = 8080, path="solr", auth = crul::auth("myusername", "myuserpassword", auth = "basic"))

This builds the url with a simple paste:
 make_url = function() {
   if (is.null(self$port)) {
     sprintf("%s://%s", self$scheme, self$host)
   } else {
     sprintf("%s://%s:%s", self$scheme, self$host, self$port)
   }
 }

Inside the call, it constructs the http client and runs a get:
   cli <- crul::HttpClient$new(url, opts = callopts, 
                               progress = progress)
   res <- cli$get(path = path, query = args)

This crul R6 object's get command just builds a GET request:
 HttpClient$get(path = NULL, query = list(), disk = NULL, stream = NULL, ...)

So when pulling data in batches, and using the Solr nextCursorMark, the iterations eventually fail and Solr hangs until it times out. It's like the server stops listening or loses its place while processing other actions for other users behind our UI. I am bypassing the UI and just hitting Solr for my data queries using this client.
Basically, I THINK I need to implement a zookeeper connection string instead of using the http request url string... but I have no idea what the string should look like. If I change the port to zookeeper's 2181, it won't authorize or connect me to solr and curl_fetch_memory gets Empty reply from server. The port
